# Ubuntu Shuts Self Down Randomly Post 21.10 Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, shutdown, 21.10

I recently upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10, the upgrade went fine, no errors or anything but now Ubuntu is shutting down randomly. Not crashing either though. The shut down prompt comes up randomly with options to shut down now or cancel with the 60 second countdown thing as if I had told it to shut down but even when I hit cancel immediately, the computer shuts off.

(This is on a System 76 Lemur that did not have this problem prior to the upgrade.)

Sorry, I'm a bit scant on the details, I'm not sure what would even be relevant because I have no idea what could even cause it to bring up the shut down dialog and then just shut off no matter what?

Editing to add the relevant section from /var/log/syslog as requested. Sorry it took so long to add. Earlier today it shut itself off twice within 20 minutes of each other but, of course,  as soon as I was waiting to find an exact time for it to check the log as I didn't remember the exact previous time, it takes 2+ hours to shut itself off again.
Anyway here is the syslog for the last time it shut down, this is the whole exact minute so I hope whatever is causing the problem is in there. I looked at what it was but this is beyond me.

```
Nov  7 22:02:10 mildred systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred NetworkManager[3396]: <info>  [1636340571.9197] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SIT
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred dbus-daemon[3395]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=0 pid=3396 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred telegram-deskto[5110]: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotAllowed: This call is not available inside the sandbox
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred sh[10132]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred dbus-daemon[3395]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred whoopsie[4648]: [22:02:51] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred whoopsie[4648]: [22:02:51] offline
Nov  7 22:02:51 mildred NetworkManager[3396]: <info>  [1636340571.9972] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov  7 22:02:52 mildred telegram-deskto[5110]: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotAllowed: This call is not available inside the sandbox
Nov  7 22:02:52 mildred whoopsie[4648]: [22:02:52] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  7 22:02:52 mildred whoopsie[4648]: [22:02:52] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov  7 22:02:52 mildred whoopsie[4648]: [22:02:52] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov  7 22:02:52 mildred whoopsie[4648]: [22:02:52] Found usable
connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov  7 22:02:52 mildred telegram-deskto[5110]: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotAllowed: This call is not available inside the sandbox
Nov  7 22:02:52 mildred whoopsie[4648]: [22:02:52] online
```

Comment: To (hopefully) find out what caused the shutdown select "No" (or whatever option is provided like that) to not shutdown now. Then open the terminal and use `journalctl -b-0` (That is a zero at the end not an Ohh). Then press the `End` key. Copy and paste the lines shown in the terminal into your question. Please don't use a screen shot of your terminal screen. That makes it impossible for us to copy and paste any error messages into *Google Search Engine*

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. See, even if I hit Cancel (the no option) the computer immediately shuts down. The prompt may as well not even come up for how useful it actually is at the time. I don't suppose that would work post starting the computer again?

Comment: If you have previous boot logs saved [How to find previous boot log after Ubuntu 16.04+ restarts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts/1008210#1008210) You can use `journalctl -b-1` otherwise you can use `gedit /var/log/syslog` and scroll to the point in time when it shut down. BTW to address someone use `@TheirName` in your comment otherwise they may not see your message. So if you want me to see a comment use `@WinEunuuchs2Unix` somewhere in the comment.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've added the section of the syslog that was from when it shut down last. Oh, and thanks for telling me about addressing someone specific, I didn't know that.

Comment: Can you rule out this isn't a hardware problem?  That is, the on/off button is "sticky" and it isn't inadvertently being triggered.  That probably isn't the cause, but it would be helpful if you rule out the obvious first.

Comment: I don't use Telegram but I'm thinking if you disable it and the problem goes away then that was the cause.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That'd be pretty weird since I've used it on this computer for years and I don't think there's been any major updates but I'll try disabling it to see.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I tried disabling Telegram but it just shut down again anyway. This time and maybe the last one it didn't even give me the shut down dialog like it was before.

Comment: @Ray Its a laptop so I propped the lid just open enough that there was clearance above the power button but still left it outputting to my external monitor but the problem persists.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if the power button could be broken.  It's a toggle switch...so...it can turn off.  I guess this isn't a dual boot machine?  What if you boot it up with a USB drive with Ubuntu on it.  And just work on it for the same amount of time...  If it also switches off, then it's your button.  If it doesn't, then it's the installation of Ubuntu.  How does this sound?

Comment: @AlexSmargle You can search for similar problems here. Like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370412/ubuntu-21-10-upgrade-crashes-randomly-with-a-black-screen

Comment: @Ray That was such a good idea, I had to go try it out so quickly I forgot to say anything. I ran the computer through about a full 24 hours off the USB to check and the problem doesn't seem to exist when running off the USB so I will just boot normally long enough to grab what little stuff I keep on it and then just do a clean install. Thanks so much!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I just wanted to also thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!  But interesting...that means there is something "wrong" with your installation that's causing it?  Well, one thing you could consider is to try Ubuntu 21.04 -- go back a version so that you at least have a working system.  Of course, if you don't have data on the system (since you backed it all up), you can try Ubuntu 21.10 again and if that doesn't work, then go back a version.  Strange problem, though...  Good luck with it!

Comment: @AlexSmargle No problem. BTW have you tried booting with the previous kernel version from your Grub Advanced Menu yet?